# Geometry Nodes: Creating a path of blocks falling onto a curve sequentially from its beginning to its end

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

Trying to create a path of blocks falling onto a curve sequentially from its beginning to its end. Right now this only works if the clockwise and counterclockwise rotations of the curve alternate.
[image]

If there are two turns in the same direction, then the tree does not work correctly.
[image]

I think the problem is that I am subtracting the position from the Sample Curve node. But so far I can not find an alternative way.
[image: Node Tree]

Comment: You are using data from before the Resample Curve, which is causing the issue, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it with Spline Parameter:
[image]

Now it works correctly.
[image]